# Insert into create new table

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, insert

I have two large tables and want to combine all of the column names (not as a view) into a new table.

I **do not have permission** to right click on each table and choose CREATE TO SCRIPT, so I was wondering if there is a way to INSERT both Tables into a new table without specifying the column data types?

Comment: you can't do it directly, as you would need to specify how to combine the two datasets.

Comment: @Viruzzo That isn't necessarily true; you can use `CROSS JOIN` (as I mentioned in my answer).

Comment: true, but then he would obtain a table with the Cartesian product of the two. I guess he should make clear what kind of result he desires.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```sql
SELECT top 0 *
INTO NewTable
FROM BigTable1
    CROSS JOIN BigTable2
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you have permissions for the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema, you can generate a `CREATE TABLE` script via a select statement on the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` table, which also contains the column data types.

Answer (score 14):

For T-SQL,

```
SELECT ...
INTO MyTable
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `SELECT INTO` TSQL query - see [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

If you have create rights you should be able to use an:

`INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT` statement to do this.

EDIT:

I had it wrong

```
SELECT * INTO MYNEWTABLE FROM MYSOURCETABLE
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO` will not create a new table.