# How to create a table from select query result in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a table from select query result in SQL Server, I tried

```
create table temp AS select.....
```

but I got an error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Comment: Create table temp as Select 1 from dual --(from Oracle)

Comment: Can the mark as duplicate be undone?  The other question linked to is much less clear and has fewer answers.

Comment: Earlier duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8314435/946850

Answer (score 463, accepted):

Use following syntax to create new table from old table in SQL server 2008

```
Select * into new_table  from  old_table
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Where is the `SELECT` query?

Comment: @Jason: It's right there. It's all around the `INTO` clause...

Comment: @LukasEder No, he means the `select` that would be there in `CREATE TABLE...AS SELECT...` which is currently where Sanjeev has `old_table`. This is a nice line of code but it lacks the functionality of CTAS because it's only selecting from a table, not a `SELECT` statement, which is the point of doing CTAS

Comment: @Hack-R: [`SELECT * INTO new_table FROM (SELECT ...) as [fancy derived table]`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/40242)

Comment: Select * into your_new_table_name  from  
(your select query here) as virtual_table_name
table will be created with "your_new_table_name".

Comment: SELECT INTO is seriously deficient as is declare TABLE when you want to create duplicate table on the fly, in order to copy out records to temp table modify then then add them back as appended records. You there is already an object named 'x' in the database if 'x' was your temp database name. And the caveat being you don't want to specify all the column names again. It's meta data, should be easy to do. This is where create table as shines

Comment: This solution still worked for me in 2019

Comment: Great, thank you @Hack-R . What does the  `as [fancy derived table]` do? It doesn't seem to matter what I put inside it

Comment: @FranLegon https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas

Answer (score 123):

use `SELECT...INTO`

> **The SELECT INTO statement creates a new table and populates it with
>   the result set of the SELECT statement.** SELECT INTO can be used to
>   combine data from several tables or views into one table. It can also
>   be used to create a new table that contains data selected from a
>   linked server.

Example,

```
SELECT col1, col2 INTO #a -- <<== creates temporary table
FROM   tablename
```

- [Inserting Rows by Using SELECT INTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190750.aspx)

Standard Syntax,

```
SELECT  col1, ....., col@      -- <<== select as many columns as you want
        INTO [New tableName]
FROM    [Source Table Name]
```

Comment: this should be marked as correct answer.

Comment: Agreed. This is the correct answer.

Comment: I found the quoted doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15. While this works great for SQL Server, it appears `SELECT ... INTO` is not standard SQL (and thus not portable to other DBMS's) - sometimes similar syntax does not create a new table, but instead appends the data into an existing table, e.g. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html.

Answer (score 35):

Please be careful,
MSSQL: `"SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM OldTable"`

is not always the same as 
MYSQL: `"create table temp AS select.."`

I think that there are occasions when this (in MSSQL)
does not guarantee that all the fields in the new table are of the same type as the old.

For example :

```
create table oldTable (field1 varchar(10), field2 integer, field3 float)
insert into oldTable (field1,field2,field3) values ('1', 1, 1)
select top 1 * into newTable from oldTable
```

does not always yield:

```
create table newTable (field1 varchar(10), field2 integer, field3 float)
```

but may be:

```
create table newTable (field1 varchar(10), field2 integer, field3 integer)
```

Comment: This is correct. There are a ton of repetitive solutions above that all miss this critical distinction.

Comment: from official docs for **'SELECT - INTO Clause (Transact-SQL)'** : "Each column in new_table has the same name, data type, nullability, and value as the corresponding expression in the select list."  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql). Please, forgive my ignorance, am I missing something?

Comment: @HEDMON I don't think this was maybe the case when this answer was posted. I just tested the code above got the answer as in the official docs. field3 was created with float datatype like on the old table.

Answer (score 20):

Please try:

```
SELECT * INTO NewTable FROM OldTable
```

Answer (score 17):

Try using SELECT INTO....

```
SELECT ....
INTO     TABLE_NAME(table you want to create)
FROM source_table
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Select [Column Name] into [New Table] from [Source Table]
```