# Why do I get an error when I execute SQL query "Create Table Tablename As"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why do I get an error when I execute the below T-SQL query?

```
CREATE TABLE TblCustomer 
 AS (SELECT * FROM Customer);
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

I am trying to create Tblcustomer table same as Customer table

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683758/how-to-create-a-table-from-select-query-result-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clone your table with data then query in SQL Server is

```
 select * into table2 from table1
```

If you want to just copy the table schema not data then query in SQL Server is

```
 select * into table2 from table1 where 1=0
```

Comment: It's **important** to note that this is for **SQL Server** - not generally for "sql" ...... SQL is **not** SQL Server - SQL is also used by MySQL, Oracle, Postgres etc. - and some of those systems handle this task differently....

Answer (score 0):

This is Oracle syntax; in SQL Server try:

```
select * 
into TblCustomer 
from customer;
```