# Cloning a table without importing row data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I need to make a provisionary table (`TAB_PROV`). This table will have its origin in a main table (`TAB_MAIN`). I need everything from the main table, except the data (rows).

I searched for some examples and none of them worked for me

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_PROV LIKE TAB_MAIN

CREATE TABLE TAB_PROV AS TAB_MAIN
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a table from select query result in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683758/how-to-create-a-table-from-select-query-result-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Yes, it worked!!! I made an adaption, I used "SELECT * INTO TAB_PROV FROM TAB_MAIN WHERE 1 = 0"

Comment: Specify precisely what "everything" means to you. Permissions? Indexes? Filegroup? Primary key? etc. Usually it is a good thing to **avoid** duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply do:

```
SELECT *
FROM TAB_MAIN
INTO TAB_PROV 
WHERE 1 = 2
```

Since the `WHERE` condition will never be true, no data is ever copied - but the **table structure** is replicated - `TAB_PROV` is created and has the same column as `TAB_MAIN`. This does **NOT** however copy any constraints (check or default constraints) or triggers over - it **only** recreates the columns (and their datatypes).

If you want a **real** and complete "copy" of your table, then you should use the "Script Table" function in SSMS to get the SQL needed for `TAB_MAIN` and then adapt it to create `TAB_PROV` from it.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Management Studio, you can right-click the table and select

```
Script Table as -> Create To -> New Query Editor Window
```

This will create just the table creation script for you.

You can also try the code below but it will copy everything.

```
SELECT * 
INTO NewTable 
FROM OldTable

TRUNCATE TABLE NewTable
```

Comment: Is there anyway to copy it without copying data?