# create a table based on the results (output) of previous queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can I create a table based on the output of previous queries? I tried Create table as select distinct syntax but it doesn't work.
ps: the previous queries contain inner join SET dateformat dmy

```
select distinct c.peril, c.period, c.eventid, c.eventdate, c.loss_index_2016,
                c.loss_index_20182019, a.eventdatetime, b.region, a.year,a.eventid
from RetroNCTJan2019v5 a
inner join retropltheader2019v5 b
    on a.segmentid=b.segmentid
inner join Index2019 c
    on b.region = c.peril and a.Year = c.period and
       a.eventid=convert(numeric(30,0),convert(float(28),c.eventid)) and
       month(eventdate) = month(eventdatetime) and day(eventdate)=day(eventdatetime)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a table from select query result in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683758/how-to-create-a-table-from-select-query-result-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: `DISTINCT` in a joined query usually indicates poorly though-out joins, which should possibly be `EXISTS` or `IN`

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you insert the results of a `SELECT` into a new table using `INTO`:

```
select distinct c.peril, c.period, c.eventid,c.eventdate, c.loss_index_2016, c.loss_index_20182019,
      a.eventdatetime, b.region, a.year,a.eventid
into new_table
from RetroNCTJan2019v5 a join
     retropltheader2019v5 b
     on a.segmentid = b.segmentid join
     Index2019 c
     on b.region = c.peril and a.Year = c.period and 
        a.eventid = convert(numeric(30,0), convert(float(28),c.eventid)) and
        month(eventdate) = month(eventdatetime) and
        day(eventdate) = day(eventdatetime)
```

Most databases use `create table as`, which in my opinion, is a little clearer.

That said, you should learn some better coding habits:

- Use table aliases that are *meaningful*.  This usually means abbreviations of the table names.  Don't use arbitrary letters.
- Qualify *all* column references, especially when your query has more than one table reference.
- Converting to a float and then a numeric is probably unnecessary.  In fact, having to do a type conversion in a `JOIN` condition is suspicious -- and even more so when the two columns have the same name.  Same name --> same type.