# Create a table on the SQL server with the data from an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to create a table on the SQL Server with the data from an SQL query?

I am trying to make a data filter screen in an SQL database and I want to try to filter a result that has already been filtered before

If you help me with an example I appreciate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a table from select query result in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683758/how-to-create-a-table-from-select-query-result-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you use `select into`.  You can phrase this as:

```
select . . .
into <tablename>
. . . rest of query here;
```

Most other databases use `create table as`:

```
create table <tablename< as
    select . . .
    . . .;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a table using the result of a query very easily using `into`

```
select <columns> into NewTableName from <query>
```