# Create a new column for a table with select data from another table

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table that shows the date and time information of a topic.

`FirstTable` looks like this:

| id | DateP | TimeP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1397/01/02 | 01:30 |
| 2 | 1398/05/09 | 05:30 |
| 3 | 1398/06/07 | 05:10 |
| 4 | 1398/08/09 | 06:12 |
| 5 | 1399/02/01 | 07:15 |

I want to create columns for another table that are the result of selecting the DateP column and the TimeP column from FirstTable.

`SecondTable` looks like this:

| id | EmployeeID | 1397/01/02_01:30 | 1398/05/09_05:30 | 1398/06/07_05:10 | 1398/08/09_06:12 | 1399/02/01_07:15 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0;
DECLARE @DatTim NVARCHAR(50)='';
SELECT @count=  Count(*) FROM FirstTable

WHILE @i <= @count
BEGIN
    @DatTim=(select DateP+TimeP FROM FirstTable where id=@i)   
    ALTER TABLE SecondTable ADD @DatTim NVARCHAR(50);
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```

Please guide me in finding the SQL code.

Comment: I think you search this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683758/how-to-create-a-table-from-select-query-result-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Hi  László Tóth, But I want the selected data from one table to be recorded in another table as the column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1;
DECLARE @count INT = 0;
DECLARE @DatTim NVARCHAR(50)='';
Set @count=(select Count(*) FROM FirstTable)

WHILE @i <= @count
BEGIN
    Set @DatTim=(select ISNULL(DateP,'') + '_'+ISNULL(TimeP,'') FROM FirstTable where id=@i)   
    exec ('ALTER TABLE SecondTable ADD ['+@DatTim +'] int NULL')
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

These cycle row by row can be slow.

I think you should use pivot with create table.

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/pivot-dynamic-columns-sql-server-rotate-table-data-ahmed-abdelhameed
and
this
[How to create a table from select query result in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683758/how-to-create-a-table-from-select-query-result-in-sql-server-2008)